# GitHub action - display the branch name to the build name

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to have the branch displayed on every manual build with gith hub action.
For example:
https://gyazo.com/2131bf83b0df1e2157480e5be842d4fb

Instead of ONE, I should have the branch displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick test and unfortunately, it is not possible to use any context or interpolation in the workflow name.
You can however dynamically name the jobs in the workflow:

```yaml
name: 'My workflow' # This name has to be hardcoded

on: [workflow_dispatch]

# or if you need inputs
#
# on:
#  workflow_dispatch:
#    inputs:
#      myinput:
#        description: 'What your input does'
#        required: true

jobs:
  myjob:
    name: ${{ github.ref }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: [...]
```

But it won't show up on the list of runs in the Actions page of your repo.

Comment: in case if I have   workflow_dispatch, where I pass the branch as input, what would be setup then?

Comment: with that: https://gyazo.com/ca54d3e283f9d7dab0df818144e4d8d9 
The branch name does not appear:   https://gyazo.com/d5d33cae176302939db99b41daaf0651

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, it is not possible. The best you cant get is names on jobs inside the workflow. But the workflow name is static.

Comment: What I need to have as a flow:
-  workflow_dispatch: branch and server
-  based on the branch input, that branch will be used for check out
-  that branch name should appear instead of the master here: https://gyazo.com/63185d11cd62cfd58e323a94c1adfece 
- my current  yml file: https://gyazo.com/0275cda23e2041949b6b4768bbca4caa
That produces:
https://gyazo.com/56db449b0be5c5726742a53fc8f22a12 
And the branch name is not shown. Any idea how to handle that? 
@ITCharp